# How can I make list of values that aren't in pivot table?

Tags: laravel, list, foreach, pivot-table

I'm trying to list the values that are not in the pivot table.

The tables are Participantes and Eventos (Participants and Events).

This returns all Participants in the pivot table.

```
@foreach ($evento->participantes as $participante)

        <tr value="">
        <td >{{$participante->nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{$participante->apellidos}}</td>
        <td>{{$participante->sexo}}</td>
        <td>{{$participante->categoria->nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($participante->fecha_nacimiento)->age}}</td>
        <td>{{$participante->club->nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{$participante->cinturon}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id_participante[]" value="{{$participante->id_participante}}"/></td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

I thought use in_array(). So I tried

```
@foreach ($participantes as $participante)
    @if(in_array($participante,$evento->participante))
```

But "$evento->participante" is not an array, so I tried ->toArray()..but it doesn't work.

There is my Evento model with the "participantes method":

```
class Evento extends Model
{


    protected $primaryKey = 'id_evento';

    public function participantes(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Participante', 'evento_participante', 'id_evento', 'id_participante' );

    }

}
```

Thanks, sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you please post your model method participantes?

Comment: Of course. OP edited.

Answer (score 0):

relations basically returns a collection data type. So, you can use various collection methods instead of looping through the relation which is not best way to optimize queries.checkout the documentation link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

```
  // find the event 
        $event  = Event::find(1);
        $participant_ids =  $event->participants->pluck('pivot.participant_id')->toArray();

        //finding participants who are not in event
        $not_in_event = Participant::whereNotIn('id',$participant_ids)->get();

        return $not_in_event;
```